# Share and update Observable data in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have 2 components - `object-list` and `search-filter` in my app. Also I have a `fetch-service` with `getObjects(page, filter)` method. I want to implement a scenario where `object-list` fetches all data via `getObjects` method and then `search-filter` will apply some filters to `getObjects` and `object-list` should automatically update. Here is some code:

**FetchService**

```
objects: Observable<any>;    

getObjects(page: number, filter): void {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  const offset = (page - 1)* this.pageSize;
  let url = this.objectsBaseUrl;

  //apply filter
  if (filter) {
    url = `${url}?filter=${JSON.stringify(filter)}`
  }

  this.objects = this.http.get(url)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      return response.json() || {}
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**ObjectListComponent**

```
constructor(private fetch: FetchService) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fetch.getObjects(this.initialPage);
  this.objects = this.fetch.objects; // I need an Observable object to use with async pipe with *ngFor
}

getPage(page: number) {
    this.fetch.getObjects(page); //here this.objects variable probably should be update because this methods replaces this.fetch.objects
}
```

**SearchFilter**

```
constructor(private fetch: FetchService) {}

apply() {
  //some filter calculations
  this.fetch.getObjects(1, this.filter);
}
```

I don't use `subscribe` to `objects` because I put it to async pipe in `*ngFor`. But as far as I'm concerned async pipe uses `subscribe` inside. The problem is that the list updates only once when `ngOnInit` fires. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SearchFilter` component should NOT be in charge of fetching the data.

Here's how I would do it:

**1) Create 3 components**

- A **parent component**, aka  "smart component", to handle all the logic of listening to filter changes and fetching the data with `FetchService`. The parent component has two children displayed in its template:
- **First child:** `SearchFilterComponent` is a "dumb component" (or presentational component). Its only job is to emit an `@Output` event every time the filters change, passing the latest filter values to its parent.
- **Second child:** `ObjectListComponent` is also a "dumb component". Its only job is to display the list of objects provided by its parent component via an `@Input` property.

**2) Implement the following workflow**

- When filters change in `SearchFilterComponent`, emit an `@Output` event passing the latest filter values, e.g. `this.filtersChanged.emit(filters)`.
- In the parent component, listen to filter changes with `<search-filter (filtersChanged)="getObjects($event)">`. The `getObjects(filters)` method will re-fetch the objects on every filter change; it should store the fetched objects in a property of the parent component, let's call it `results`.
- Then, the parent component passes `results` to its child component `ObjectListComponent` via an @Input property called `objects`: `<object-list [objects]="results">`. The object list should refresh automatically every time the input changes.

Hopefully my explanations will make sense. Read up on @Input and @Output on the angular.io site if you're not familiar with those. I don't have time to create a Plunkr, so please post questions if anythings seems unclear.

Comment: Your approach differs from my and it needed some time to implement but it worked for me!

Comment: Glad to hear that, congrats!